# Can Redux DevTools be used to automate integration testing across a list of URLs or Actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, automated-tests, integration-testing, redux-devtools

Are there any good resources for using Redux DevTools for integration / end-to-end testing?

I see their Slider can replay events and Dispatcher executes just about anything. Can it somehow loop over a config file to replay common user flows on the site, and record the state changes along the way?

[image: f]

Comment: I ended up using Cypress